# Divs floats em um container com height auto

Tags: html, css

Estou tendo um problema para estruturar um *layout* com algumas `divs` uma do lado da outra e quando não couber mais caixa elas passem para baixo. E o *container* principal precisa aumentar de acordo com quantas caixa tiver. Mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não sei porque  não está funcionando, o container principal não aumenta de tamanho. Meu código:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="caixas"></div>
    <div class="caixas"></div>
    <div class="caixas"></div>
    <div class="caixas"></div>
    <div class="caixas"></div>
    <div class="caixas"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width:610px;
    height:AUTO;
    border:1px #FF0000 solid;    
}
.caixas{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   border:1px #00FF00 solid;
   float:left;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7Nk8/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar uma técnica conhecida como clearfix, que consiste em que o próximo elemento ou pseudo-elemento tenha `display:block;` e `clear:both;`, garantindo que ele aumente por mais que o conteúdo esteja com `float:left;`.

**Veja este exemplo:**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7Nk8/1/)

Esta mesma forma é adotada por frameworks CSS como o Twitter Bootstrap por exemplo.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo na resposta para ficar mais compreenssível.

Comment: Rapaiz muito obrigado funcionou direitinho.

Comment: Imagine ^^, estamos aqui para nos ajudar ^^

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas alterações

**CSS:**

```
#container{
    width:620px; // aumentei para 620
    height:AUTO;
    border:1px #FF0000 solid;    
}
.caixas{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   border:1px #00FF00 solid;
   display:inline-block; // retirei o float e usei display:inline-block

}
```

**Display:** [inline-block](http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)

Para visualizar o código em funcionamento clique [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/V6VkZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Eu particularmente resolvo isso com um float:left no elemento pai. Mas o correto mesmo é usar o clearfix que o amigo Diego Lopes Lima comentou.

Answer (score -3):

A propriedade CSS "overflow" especifica o que acontece se o conteúdo excede a caixa de um elemento, dando até a possibilidade de controlar as barras de rolagens laterais e horizontais.

Veja mais sobre a propriedade: [CSS Overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Utilizando ela podemos resolver o seu problema com apenas 1 linha de código, basta adicionar esta propriedade com o valor "hidden" nos estilos do seu container.

Veja como fica seu código ajustado:

```
#container{
    width:610px;
    height:AUTO;
    border:1px #FF0000 solid;  
    overflow:hidden;
}
.caixas{
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   border:1px #00FF00 solid;
   float:left; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7Nk8/3/

Comment: Sua resposta não é correta para está situação.

Comment: Interessante sua opinião. Posso saber porque pensa dessa forma?

Comment: Seu texto realmente explica a funcionalidade da propriedade `overflow` do CSS, porém neste caso o problema apontado pela pergunta é sobre o elemento que encapsula outros elementos que usam `float:left;`. Isso faz com que este elemento não aumente conforme o conteúdo a menos que um elemento ou pseudo-elemento com visualização em bloco seja colocado logo em seguida com `clear:both;`.

Comment: Creio que foi apenas uma confusão de link's, você parece ter pegado o link que eu passei na resposta para ver o erro, e acabou pegando já resolvido, por isso deve ter interpretado errado...

Comment: Talvez eu tenha feito alguma confusão nos links mesmo, mas ainda acho a minha resposta a mais adequada pra pergunta. Usar o último item com "display:block;" realmente funciona, mas pra mim isso é considerado gambiarra. Link corrigido obrigado.

Comment: Bom, considerar uma gambiarra realmente é algo de opinião própria, porém essa tecnica é utilizada como a melhor solusão por os maiores framworks CSS existentes atualmente. Incluindo Twitter Bootstrap, que é a ferramenta front end mais usada no mundo. Se você tiver uma tecnica de clearfix desconhecida mais eficiente com certeza todos nós gostariamos de entender e o criador do Twitter Bootstrap Mark Otto também ficaria feliz em atualizar o repositório.
Caso queira aprender um pouco sobre aqui está o arquivo escrito em LESS: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/clearfix.less